# Autosaving form data using ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to auto save the form data at the server side using ajax calls. I start the auto save 20 seconds after any input change. If one auto save call is in progress, I want to wait. Following are the steps I am taking. My approach depends on a javascript global variable and I have a fear that I might run into some kind of synchronization issues. Is there any other better way to do this?

```
$('input').change(function() {
            if (autoSaveInProgress == false) {
                //call ajax function in 20secodns.
                setTimeout(autoSaveFunction, 20000);
                autoSaveInProgress = true;
            }
        });
```

I set the autoSaveInProgress to false in the autoSaveFunction after receiving the response from server.

Comment: As long as you toggle autosave back to false I don't see any issues.  You need to maintain that state somewhere.

Comment: Athough JS is asynchronous in nature it is single threaded. I don't see why you will get into synchronization issues. Another thing would be to properly namespace your variable. On the webserver you might want to make sure that session lock is required for this save function. This way at a time only one ajax call will be executed at a time. You might also want to timestamp your calls just in case they reach out of order.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. In general, is this a good solution to what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just assuming that the previous call is completed after 20 seconds, I would suggest using the (jQ)xhr-objects properties:

```
var saveXhr;

function autoSave(){

    if(saveXhr && saveXhr.readyState < 4){ 
         //previous save not completed
         //do something, perhaps saveXhr.abort() or prolong the timer
    }else{
       saveXhr = $.ajax({ /* your save ajax code */ });
    }
}
```

Comment: As I indicated in my original post, I am restting the gloabl var after receiving the response from server. I am using jquery ajax always function to reset the global variable. I am not simply relying on 20second time out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using global scoped variables, you could set attributes on the element experiencing the change event. I like to use the disabled attribute.

```
var disabled = $that.attr('disabled');
if (disabled) {
    return false;
}
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

and re-enable the element, but you'll have to pass the element into the async closure(see the fiddle):

```
$that.removeAttr('disabled');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EHFZL/

You can also make your change selector more specific: http://jsfiddle.net/eHQbh/

Comment: I don't want to disable fields. Users will continue to edit data, Its more like Saving a draft (like gmail). Thanks.

Comment: I see now. Then my offered solution won't work for your intent. However, the problem I see with your current implementation, is changes taking place while your autosave is happening will be ignored and not saved.  You'll want to track somewhere that you have a pending change and save one last time before leaving the page.